# Stack overflow while using vector

Tags: c++, vector, stack-overflow

I made a program for school's little contest, I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    

int main(){
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  int c[n];
  std::vector<int> r(n);
  std::cout << "I made it through";
  //rest of program
}
```

When i type in 1000000 and press enter program crashes without a word, exit code (0xC00000FD). I presumed it happens when i initialize vector, but i though it can handle a lot more. Am i doing something wrong? I know i can use pointer but i'd prefer not to touch things that are already working.

Comment: `int c[n];` is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack is a very restricted resource.

Even though your compiler seems to implement C-style VLA's in C++ (`int c[n];`), it does not magically gain more memory.

Test 1) Success of reading `n`, and 2) `n` not being out-of-bounds for your use before executing the statement allocating that stack-array.

Default stack-size for Windows: 1MB `sizeof(int)`: 4 Thus, about 250000 fit.
Default stack size for Linux: 8MB `sizeof(int)`: 4 Thus, about 2000000 fit.

Workaround: Use dynamic allocation for the `int`s, like with a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> c(n);
```

Alternatively, at least use a smart-pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> c(new int[n]);
```

Comment: Right, i forgot about c[n]... Now i feel really dumb

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't `vector` (which uses the heap for its underlying expanding storage in most STL implementations), but `int c[n]`, which will allocate 1,000,000 4-byte integers in the stack, which is almost 4MB. On Win32 the stack is by default around 1MB, hence the overflow.

If you really need to use an array then change your `c` array to be allocated on the heap by using `new`, but don't forget to `delete[]`, otherwise use of `vector` is preferred for most expanding storage scenarios. If you need a fixed-length array then consider `array<class T, size_t N>` (new in C++11) which adds bounds-checking.

Comment: Use `vector`, not `new`

Comment: `std::array` is useful but it would blow up the stack the same way the posted code does, the size must be know at compile time, and it only does bounds-checking if you go out of your way to use the `at()` member function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to allocate the array dynamically. In C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    

int main()
{
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  int *c = new int[n];

  if(nullptr == c) {
    std::cerr << "Runtime error" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  std::vector<int> r(begin(n), end(n));
  std::cout << "I made it through";

  delete[] c;
  return 0;
}
```

Also to make the vector after you have allocated `c` dynamically you can use `begin`, `end`