# How many values can be put into an Array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, double

I wanted to read an array of double values from a file to an array. I have like 128^3 values. My program worked just fine as long as I stayed at 128^2 values, but now I get an "segmentation fault" error, even though 128^3 ≈ 2,100,000 is by far below the maximum of int. So how many values can you actually put into an array of doubles?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int LENGTH = 128;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    const int arrLength = LENGTH*LENGTH*LENGTH;
    std::string filename = "density.dat";
    std::cout << "opening file" << std::endl;
    std::ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
    std::cout << "creating array with length " << arrLength << std::endl;
    double* densdata[arrLength];


    std::cout << "Array created"<< std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i < arrLength; ++i){
        double a;

        infile >> a;
        densdata[i] = &a;
        std::cout << "read value: " << a  << " at line " << (i+1) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As many as its big. What you are actually asking is, how big is the stack.

Comment: Depends on how much stack space your build allocates.

Comment: Stack size is limited, 1mb is a typical value. When you need to store a large number of elements, use dynamic memory. Particularly I suggest use of a vector and push_back. Also, the pointers you store in densdata become invalid after each loop iteration.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538590/stack-overflow-while-using-vector

Comment: Why are you storing pointers-to-double instead of doubles?

Comment: I hoped it might fix the issue by using less memory, but I stepped back from it now :)

Comment: @Geru Well yes, having pointers to objects that do not exist is a good way to save the program from needing memory space for those objects :P

Comment: I thought, that probably the size of the object that is the array was the initial problem. So I decided to go for pointers as those pointers are int values and therefore just half the size of a double. I knew, it would cost more memory space, but the array itself would have had half the size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are allocating the array on the stack, and stack size is limited (by default, stack limit tends to be in single-digit megabytes).

You have several options:

- increase the size of the stack (`ulimit -s` on Unix);
- allocate the array on the heap using `new`;
- move to using `std::vector`.

Comment: The last two options are the same for the purposes of this question.